# BJT Circuits at DC, base current calculation

Tags: dc, bjt

I'm trying to walk through the example calculations in the attached example however I cant understand how the author gets the expression for the first step in the process. I tried making up the expression however I get stuck when equating the current. I have attached an image of the example(in Sedra&Smith 6th or 7th edition). I have also attached an image that shows my approach to step one.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume VBB to be the +5V supply and VB the actual base voltage. In that case, the last line contains two unknowns: VE and VB. As the transistor is in active mode, you get a diode drop (rule of thumb: 0.7V) between VE and VB, so substitude VE by (VB-0.7V) or VB by (VE+0.7V) and you can solve the equation.